# Dynamically Creating Multiple ListViews in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, listview

I am currently in the process of developing a basic news aggregation app in android, I know there's loads out there but i'm basically just creating one because I think its a good place to begin for someone who's just starting out with Android development.

My goal is to display articles from several feeds. Each feed will have its own horizontal sliding list, kind of like the pulse news app. So far I have managed to find a tutorial on creating a "HorizontalListView" and I now have my app displaying a basic horizontal sliding listview like below:

**Screenshot Link:** http://www.dev-smart.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/device-200x300.png

**Pulse App Screenshot:** http://a1525.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/080/Purple/v4/ba/6a/01/ba6a01d1-f0b7-4bb7-3f94-5a5761653e3c/mzl.zxnjzzmk.480x480-75.jpg

Code:

```
public class HorizontalListViewDemo extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);

    HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}

private static String[] dataObjects = new String[]{ "Text #1",
    "Text #2",
    "Text #3", "Text #4"  }; 

private BaseAdapter mAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    private OnClickListener mOnButtonClicked = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(HorizontalListViewDemo.this);
            builder.setMessage("hello from " + v);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Cool", null);
            builder.show(); 
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return dataObjects.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View retval = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) retval.findViewById(R.id.title);
        Button button = (Button) retval.findViewById(R.id.clickbutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(mOnButtonClicked);
        title.setText(dataObjects[position]);
        return retval;
    }   
};
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#000"
  >

  <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="#ddd"
  />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As I mentioned each HorizontalListView will represent 1 feed and display its associated articles as above. So my next step in this development is to try and make the creation of these HorizontalListView's dynamic so a user could declare a feed from within the app and it would then dynamically be created below the already defined ones.

Disregarding all other efforts involved in that process I am really only asking for help with creating a new HorizontalListView that can recycle the already defined XML listview layout id="listview". I know I could get this to work if I where to pre-define all feeds and just create unique XML  layouts with unique id's, but I'm wondering is there a way I can define a new HorizontalListView that reuses existing layouts.

I hope you guys can maybe shed some light on this for me.

Thanks

**Update 1:**
using Views?

```
//Defining main XML file "listviewdemo.xml"
setContentView(R.layout.listviewdemo);
//Creating a new view to apply to my HorizontalListViews, /res/layout/listviewStyle.xml
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewStyle, null);

//Defining my first HorizontalListView      
HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listviewReuse);
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: I got a little lost reading the question. Are you familiar with "Inflater.inflate"? This will allow you to load a layout at runtime and have it attached to a parent.

Comment: Hi there, you can get some basic idea from [here](http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/04/horizontally-sliding-grid-of-images-in.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
HorizontalListView listview = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
```

This line will always return the first view found with R.id.listview. Not very nice when you have multiple list views.

Now instead of calling Activity.findViewById() call findViewById() on a subview. You can contain each listview inside of a layout. Then call findViewById to find the layout that is the parent to the listview. The call findViewById on the layout.

Once you have found the listView the first time remember it for later use.

In the updated code you posted, remove this line. It is not doing anything b/c this view is not apart of the layout R.layout.listviewdemo.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewStyle, null);
```

Then in The xml for R.layout.listviewdemo add both listviews to the same .xml (assuming that is your goal). Whatever the case maybe you should add all of your views to the same layout then retrieve the views using `findViewById`.

Comment: Yeah the XML for the listview is currently defined in listview.xml under res/layout. The exact XML is described above. See I figured when I first started messing around with listviews that I could reuse the already defined XML id's when defining a new listview i.e. HorizontalListView listview2 = (HorizontalListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); but when i do this the 2nd listview doesn't appear in my app. If i duplicate the listview XML and apply a new id i.e. listview2 it does appear. So i'm assuming you can only use any ID once?

Comment: Ok, you are definately misunderstanding something based on that comment. 1) findViewById will find the first view with that id in the layout. If you have 2 listview in one layout then don't call findViewById on the activity, call it on a sub view that only has 1 listview. 2) You can't call findViewById and expect it to create a 2nd layout, you need 2 listviews defined in your layout.

Comment: Yeah i'm definitely misunderstanding something alright, after taking another look at my code I am now trying to create a View using an id from a second XML file "listviewStyle.xml" which only has 1 id and that is listviewReuse. See update in question for more info. So far this creates a blank activity. HorzListview is now not appearing.